# Bag file with Karto

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friend.

I have a bag file and I run this bag file with gMapping, without any problem. Now, I want to run(autonom) this same bag file with KartoMapping(nav2d_karto). So, how can I do this?

Thanks for your help...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222050/bag-file-with-karto/) by [kursatufuk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25261/kursatufuk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same as with gmapping.
Create a launch file (take care about topic remappings), configure karto (take care about the frame ids), and go.

Afaik, the only thing karto needs is a laser scan and the tf from `odom` to `base_link` (or whatever you configure it to be)... So the exact same thing as  gmapping...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kursatufuk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25261/kursatufuk/) on 2015-12-09**:
Hey mig! You are really good man.

I glanced /karto_out topic and MultiMapper.cpp. So MultiMapper.cpp so complex. I didn't understand methods :)

What did you mean "configure karto"? Add or remove some code to the MultiMapper.cpp? Or you mean only tf transform?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-12-10**:
well, there are parameter/config files (yaml files). This is the configuration. Check out the example launch and config files [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_karto)

**Comment by [kursatufuk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25261/kursatufuk/) on 2015-12-13**:
Thanks mig!